# Read AGS type file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a special type of file (the format is called AGS) which looks like in the image:

[image]

This is basically a TEXT file, which contains many tables with different dimensions inside, separated by 2 (but sometimes more) empty rows. As you might guess, the problem is related to the fact that these tables have different number of columns and obviously different column names.
The first row in each table (here tables are denoted as GROUP) shows the name of the table, e.g. LOCA, HDPH, etc. The second row shows the column names. The third row shows the units of each column. All the other rows show the observations. In each row, columns are separated by commas and values are inside double quotes.

I am struggling to read this type of file. The ideal output would be to have each of these tables into separated data frames. Any help and ideas are much appreciated.
An example file can be downloaded here: [example AGS file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/104dQ95ebSfGSaNUS3yyxgD-wqYJXh0Tt/view?usp=sharing)